# Ext4-fs error dm-3

Tags: corruption

I tried to re-mount a LVM:

```
mount /dev/vg1/lv1 /home
```

buty I got this message:

```
[409104.164857] EXT4-fs (dm-3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[409104.165223] EXT4-fs (dm-3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[409104.165568] EXT4-fs (dm-3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[409104.165916] FAT-fs (dm-3): invalid media value (0x64)
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

I am new to working with linux. I wrote:

```
cp /var/log/*.gz.tar /dev/mapper/vg1/lv1
```

I thought that that way I could copy the files.

So until I did a server reboot. When the server started, I got a message saying "Press M to log into maintenance mode. When I noticed that home was gone.
I started researching and found the LVM topic. That's when I found out that I made a mistake wanting to copy the files the way I mentioned above.

This is my case and I would be very grateful for your help and opinion.
Thanks to all of you who spent your time reading my situation.

Answer (score 0):

You basically destroyed the filesystem at `/dev/vg1/lv1` by writing over the block device. Depending on the size of the files copied over, you might recover *something* out of the filesystem, but this is the time to use your backup, if there was anything of importance (you have the backup in that case, of course).

Comment: I tried copying a 350MB file

Comment: Then the first 350MB of the filesystem is now overwritten. I'm guessing the filesystem was significantly larger than that, so there may be recoverable data. But a lot of important filesystem metadata was probably located in that overwritten 350 MB, so you might need tools like `PhotoRec` to go through the remaining space and recover any recognizable files.

Answer (score 0):

I have been studing about LVM, but I can't  undertand the line in my error message:

[409104.164857] EXT4-fs (dm-3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[409104.165223] EXT4-fs (dm-3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[409104.165568] EXT4-fs (dm-3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[409104.165916] FAT-fs (dm-3): invalid media value (0x64)<----<<<<<This part. Why Fat-fs? What do it do in LVM????